# files under /fonts cannot be loaded in production but it works perfectly in local

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, font-awesome

after packaging my react js application into spring boot , all files under asset/fonts cannot be loaded , it works perfectly in local but the issue appears after running the app in prouction [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4o2Y.png)

i tried `.antMatcher("/assets/fonts/**).permitAll().antMatcher("/assets/fonts/**).permitAll()` into my spring security config but doesn't solve the problem

then i changed all files under /fonts permission to wrx-wrx-wrx which make able to load styles from these files but the problem persists in console as shown in picture

Comment: A couple of ideas to try. Do you have access to the production logs? They may have some more information on why the request is forbidden. 
I am guessing your deploying your application as JAR. Try running that same JAR locally and see if you can reproduce the error. The react app might be packaged differently within the JAR than it is when running in an IDE.

Comment: i tried to run the jar locally it works without problem , the problem appears when i run the jar on my vps